# How recover deleted files from other computer?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I moved a html file from my computer to another and accidentally deleted it from that computer which I accessed from my computer like this: `\\name\folder`

As a result the file did not go recycle bin. I tried `ntfsundelete` and it did found the file on my computer but when I recovered, it looks like as if you opened binary file with notepad. I then tried *Recuva* and it says that part of the file is overwritten.

Is there any chance to recover it? Can I recover it from another computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to turn the computer off now and then run something like GetDataBack NTFS in various modes (undelete, systematic damage, sequential damage) and see if you can recover the file. Depending on how big the hard drive is you're going to be there for a while.

1. DO NOT USE THAT HARD DRIVE, if you access it for anything other than reading then you are at risk of overwriting the file more (Make sure you know what "read" is, don't browse the drive: explorer.exe writes metadata, thumbs.db etc)
2. If the file has been overwritten... the file has been overwritten. Restore from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

If data recovery didn't work on your PC, try the PC you moved the file from. No, you cannot do this remotely. (Or at least, shouldn't).

Personally I like the command line tool [findntfs](http://www.partitionsupport.com/utilities.htm).

As [taspeotis](https://superuser.com/questions/99744/recover-deleted-files-from-other-computer/99750#99750) says, you should be careful not to write to the drive. If it is the system drive, you should not boot it as lots of disk writes occur at boot. Ideally, mount the drive in read-only mode.

There are lots of threads on superuser about [data recovery](https://superuser.com/search?q=data+recovery).

Answer (score 0):

No way, you can't recover deleted files from the other computer but the one that you deleted your data and files from.

There are some 3rd party recovery tool that claim they can do the job for you. You may try! Like Recuva - Freeware.